# How to format dates in Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am try to format the date response to `"2021-01-20T23:36:42.481+00:00"` but I end up with a response looking like `1611178602481` have tried setting the date format on `application.properties` file to `spring.jackson.date-format=yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` nothing

what I have done so far

```
   @GetMapping("/users/{id}/activation-date")
    public ResponseEntity<Date> getUserActivationDate(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        User user = userRepository.findById(id).get();
        return ResponseEntity.ok(user.getActivation_date());
    }
```

my model class

```
public class User {
  

      @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long id;
    
        @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
        private Date activation_date = new Date();
    
       
    
         public Date getDatecreated() {
                return datecreated;
            }
        
            public void setDatecreated(Date datecreated) {
                this.datecreated = datecreated;
            }
```

thank you for your assistance

Comment: [You can NOT create a formatted Date object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66664791/10819573). Also, the `java.util` date-time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html). Learn about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ZonedDateTime` class instead of `Date`. Below is the code snippet

```
public class User {

   private Long id;

   private ZonedDateTime activation_date = ZonedDateTime.now();
}
```

Controller

```
@GetMapping("/users/{id}/activation-date")
public ResponseEntity<ZonedDateTime> getUserActivationDate(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
            User user =new User(); //Use your custom login here
            return ResponseEntity.ok(user.getActivation_date());
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Hi @Avinash am getting the date from a database, but it doesnt come formatted

Comment: Hi @arriff If you want the date as it is in Database, Then use `String` instead of `Date`. `private String activation_date;`

Comment: it returns correctly as `2021-01-20 23:36:42.4810000`, how can I have it return as `"2021-01-20 23:36:42.4810000"`

Comment: While returing `String` you will get the `"` automatically. See my screenshot in the above answer. If you need extra `"`  then use `return ResponseEntity.ok("\""+user.getActivation_date()+("\"");`

Answer (score 0):

Add a dependency on JodaTime https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/joda-time/joda-time.

It's an extensive library for manipulating, handling and formatting dates and you'll never need anything else ;)

https://www.joda.org/joda-time/key_format.html